# pass a variable to curl from get request php

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php
@$test = $GET['link'];
$url = 'http://cf3.fancyimgs.com/310/20130521/367302239598940361_92b5e3190b3f.jpg';
$ch = curl_init($test);
$fc = fopen('c.jpg', 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fc);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fc);
?>
```

this is not working in  codeigniter, above is my php code to get image from an url that i passed through GET 
and am not getting the image from the get request url
can anyone help me to solve this.....
and below is the link from where i send the image url

```
<a href="index.php?link=<?php echo $url ;?>">click to download</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
$_GET['link']
 ^
 |--- Note the underline
```

Not

```
$GET['link']
```

And

```
echo urlencode($url) // would be better approach ...
```

Comment: +1 for the approach to point out the error. One of the best way i have seen until now to highlight the error.